# asp.net-web-api2 individual user account with Custom Database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, identity

I am new to asp.net web api , I need to  create project with individual user account , 
But I don't need identity database ,
I need to use my database , (database already exist) .

so when check username and password , check it from my database and tables (it's different structure of asp identity DB )

and I don't need to register and create the datatables in my database ?

what the changes should i do ? 
and is there any tutorial  to work on it  ?

Comment: The identity is not mandatory. You can use your own tables to make the authentication system.

Comment: @FabioLuz
Can you give me any way yo do that ?

Comment: Take a look at this article http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/. In the step 10, instead of using asp.net identity, search for the user in your current context, using your own tables